# Can you configure a maximum API Gateway or Lambda body size for a POST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Can API Gateway be configured to allow a maximum of (for example) 100KB bodies in a POST call for a given HTTP/REST endpoint?

Max for Amazon API Gateway is 10MB and 6MB for Lambda, but I want the other direction. I want to enforce a maximum size lower than the default at the API Gateway layer before it gets to my lambda.

And would any rejected requests be considered part of the billable total requests?

Comment: you could attach a WAF to it and write a rule to restrict incoming request body sizes, but I'm not aware of a way to do it natively in API Gateway

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but as far as I know API gateway does not support this functionality natively. As a work around, if you put CloudFront in front of your API gateway, you could run a Lambda@Edge on each request to check that the length is less than 100,000 characters (which equals 100KB). You’d pay for Lambda@Edge invocations and CloudFront requests, but it should be pretty economical, even at scale, and Lambda@Edge is very fast; we use it for image resizing and it added ~100ms to our requests, barely noticeable, but certainly measurable.

Comment: Thank you, both. Knowing where not to look is often as helpful as where to look.